# ios making Masked BlurView with Stroke

Tags: ios, gpuimage, morphological-analysis

I have a little advanced question I want to make a custom shape blur on a png image that is half transparent and the png has transparent areas , and then drawing a stroke around the image (avoiding the transparent area in png image).
I tried using GPUImage for making blue over image but I get blocked at drawing  a stroke around the non-transparent part of the image .
I tried using this method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15010886/4641980)
But the stroke is half transparent (following the fact that the image non-transparent part is half transparent ).

I need your help to make this done .
This example is nearly what i mean

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdITu.png

I have spent alot of time searching and trying but so far in vain , I will be so thankful for your help .
Thank you.

Comment: if the shape of blur image is fixed, you can mask the blur image via "CAShapeLayer". "CAShapeLayer" has strock property.

Comment: if you mean fixed path like fixed rectangle or circle , im afraid its not . its random like the shape in the link above . @HarvantS.

Comment: that can be draw with CGPath or UIBezierPath (i prefer). Just use answered code with your path. Try once , you might get some help. The path could be static but unusual in shape.

Comment: @HarvantS. I have not worked with paths before but seems like i have to finally , I will do my search for using them and then combine your code , Thanks man for your help for advance .

Comment: just try with simple shapes. For more complex shapes you can ask for a SVG image of shape and use that image in `PaintCode` tool. It will give you path from the SVG image.

Comment: Oh thats awesome , You saved me alot of time i was about to search for that . Thanks man, You are the best , (y) @HarvantS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "CAShapeLayer" to clip (or mask) the blur image. For this you need a CGPath of the masking (or clipping) shape.

```
CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame=CGRectMake(-imageView.frame.origin.x, -imageView.frame.origin.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
pathLayer.path = yourClippingPath.CGPath;
pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.lineWidth = 6.0;
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
[imageView.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];
```

Comment: I Just Another Problem with clipping the path , The mask applied as a stroke not clipping whats inside the path , I explained the problem here , http://stackoverflow.com/q/30938134/4641980
I will be Thankful if You can help me with it , Thank you @Harvant S.