# clip-masking uiview with CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a problem clipping a view using CAShapeLayer-UIBezierPath , I want to clip the content but I end up  getting a stroke (frame) with that UIBezierPath , This is my code

```
UIBezierPath *path2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path2Path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(206.745, 0)];
[path2Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(206.745, 97.613)];
[path2Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 97.613)];
[path2Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[path2Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(87.28, 0)];
[path2Path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(103.808, 12.118) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(87.28, 0) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(86.555, 12.118)];
[path2Path addCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(119.466, 0) controlPoint1:CGPointMake(121.061, 12.118) controlPoint2:CGPointMake(119.466, 0)];
[path2Path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(206.745, 0)];
[path2Path closePath];

[path2Path addClip];

CAShapeLayer *pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
pathLayer.frame=MYVIEW.bounds;
pathLayer.path = path2Path.CGPath;

pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
pathLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

pathLayer.fillRule=kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
[MYVIEW.layer setMask:pathLayer];
[MYVIEW.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

MYVIEW.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

The result of this code is just a green stroke line ,the bounds is empty ,
like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aehdo.png

However , I want to make the bounds green , clipped by that stroke

Comment: You want to show the only part of image inside bezier path. Right?

Comment: yes exactly . @RajeshMaurya

Comment: May i know? where you write the code? In Viewcontroller or created UIView subclass.

Comment: Do you added image into MYVIEW?

Comment: @RajeshMaurya 
 
nope , its normal view with subviews inside (but for now it just has background color ) , I want to clip subviews or the background color for this view . the main problem is that the mask applies as a stroke not as a content inside the view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Bezier Path as Clipping Mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410146/use-bezier-path-as-clipping-mask)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

as [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567) said **You can do this easily by setting your view's layer mask to a CAShapeLayer.**

```
UIBezierPath *myClippingPath = ...
CAShapeLayer *mask           = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path                    = myClippingPath.CGPath;
myView.layer.mask            = mask;
```

**In Swift**

```
let myClippingPath = UIBezierPath( ... )
let mask           = CAShapeLayer()
mask.path          = myClippingPath.CGPath
myView.layer.mask         = mask
```

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for answers guys.

In case someone can't find suitable answer on SO for this question for hours, like i just did, i've assembled a working gist in Swift 2.2 for masking/clipping UIView with CGRect/UIBezierPath:

https://gist.github.com/Flar49/7e977e81f1d2827f5fcd5c6c6a3c3d94

```
extension UIView {
    func mask(withRect rect: CGRect, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        if inverse {
            path.appendPath(UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds))
            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        }

        maskLayer.path = path.CGPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }

    func mask(withPath path: UIBezierPath, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let path = path
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        if inverse {
            path.appendPath(UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds))
            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        }

        maskLayer.path = path.CGPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let viewSize = targetView.bounds.size
let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: viewSize.width - 20*2, height: viewSize.height - 20*2)

// Cuts rectangle inside view, leaving 20pt borders around
targetView.mask(withRect: rect, inverse: true)

// Cuts 20pt borders around the view, keeping part inside rect intact
targetView.mask(withRect: rect)
```

Hope it will save someone some time in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can even improve @Eugene's response (greate work, mate!) with corner radius

```
  extension UIView {  
    func mask(withRect rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let path = cornerRadius > 0 ?
            UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius) :
            UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        if inverse {
            path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: bounds))
            maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        }

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```