# How to crop Image as per the top front image?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

My purpose is to export `UIImage` from the `UIView`. so I want to add clear border over red circle so the output image looks like 2nd image.

[image]
Now I want something like that: I want to add clear background over the red circle so the output image look something like below image. (I know if I add clear border then I can't achieve this so please suggest me to achieve this)

[image]

Here I have just added only color, This 2 color are actually images

## Edit

I'm able to do this by using the below code but the cutting area is not rounding.

```
func cut(hole: CGRect, inView v: UIView) {
    let p:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    p.addRect(CGRect.init(x: v.frame.origin.x, y: v.frame.origin.y, width: v.frame.width, height: v.frame.height))
    p.addRect(hole)

    let s = CAShapeLayer()
    s.path = p
    s.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd

    v.layer.mask = s
}
```

Here is my Demo Link: **https://gofile.io/?c=jukO6B**

Current Output

[image]

Any help will be appreciated to do this.

Comment: you want to remove white background of car image ..??

Comment: yes, but Ethan Hunt image will not be cut at the same frame where car white background is there. please review my updated question.

Comment: are you using any code to do that ? if yes please show us.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary, no, I wasn't using any code to do that, I want to do this by UIView hierarchy inside UIStoryBoard.

Comment: you are using too many views to do it, you should do it by code, you can't make image round without `layer` property of view object and its not a trick, its straight forward to round an image.

Comment: one more thing - is size of Ethan Hunt's image is fixed or it vary with device ?

Comment: you are already o half way, as i said in answer, three circle's, one user, one border and third one is badge, badge and border share same centre, border will be slightly bigger than badge and gonna mask user. so final result would be user masked with border and badge at corner.

Comment: @HarvantS.Choudhary, If I add the border with any color except then CLEAR color then only it works. if I add CLEAR border over red circle then it wan't works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200881/discussion-between-harvant-s-choudhary-and-kuldeep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution by making some modification in this answer as per the requirement: [How can I 'cut' a transparent hole in a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452159/how-can-i-cut-a-transparent-hole-in-a-uiimage/42331358#42331358)

```
func cut(hole: CGRect, inView v: UIView) {
    let p:CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
    v.clipsToBounds = false
    p.addRect(CGRect.init(x: v.frame.origin.x, y: v.frame.origin.y, width: v.frame.width, height: v.frame.height))
    p.addRoundedRect(in: CGRect.init(x: self.vwCarContainer.frame.origin.x, y: self.vwCarContainer.frame.origin.y, width: self.vwCarContainer.frame.width, height: self.vwCarContainer.frame.height), cornerWidth: self.vwCarContainer.layer.cornerRadius, cornerHeight: self.vwCarContainer.layer.cornerRadius)

    let s = CAShapeLayer()
    s.path = p
    s.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd

    v.layer.mask = s
}
```

Thanks to all who help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit -** It turned out OP needed a completely different effect than what he initially showed us.

Here is my suggestion to him -

[clip-masking uiview with CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938134)

You have to do something like this, create three view, one user's image, second badge's image and third for transparent border which gonna mask users's image. both badge's image and its border must share same centre point.

---

You need to change `layer` property of UIView. You have to provide user defined properties of view's layer -

- Key Path: `layer.cornerRadius`, Type: Number, Value: (whatever radius you want)
- Key Path: `layer.masksToBounds`, Type: Boolean, Value: checked

As you said you want to do it with storyboard so here an example of it -

[image: Check this]

**Set background color 'clear' of both views, you are good to go.**

**P.S.** in example sizes of both views are fixed, if your view have dynamic sized (or adaptive size), you should do round your views by code.

Comment: I think you don't understood my question properly or I was unable to express it. let me update my question

Comment: please check updated answer. it wasn't complete earlier.

Comment: as I can see in your attached screen, I know it to do this thing but I don't want to do this

Comment: okay then I really don't understand what you are asking, explain a bit.

Comment: review my edited question. I attached the output image.

Comment: okay so you don't want extra while color around ethan and car's image ? and no extra padding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200814/discussion-between-harvant-s-choudhary-and-kuldeep).